# Jinja join list of strings if substring match

Tags: jinja2

Is it possible to do something like this in jinja2:

```
my_list = ['foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2', 'bar2'] # could be any number of foo's and bar's
[i for i in my_list if 'foo' in i]
```

I was looking at map and join, something like:

```
{% my_list|map('???')|join(' ') %}
```

But I can't find a filter that would like me do any sort of wildcard searches. The two closest ones look like 'sameas' and 'equalto' but those don't quiet work.

Comment: If you're using the development version of Jinja2, there's a new filter called 'select', which might well do what you want. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of Jinja2 (2.7 or later), there's a new filter called 'select', which seems to do what you want. [jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select) You will probably have to write your own test for this, and pass it into the jinja2 object when you instantiate it.

```
{{ foobars|select("test") }}
```

If you're on an even more up to date version (2.8 or later), you can also use block assignments http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#block-assignments

```
{% set my_foo_bars %}
    {%- for item in my_list %}
        {%- if item %}
 {{item}}
        {% endif -%}
    {% endfor -%}
{% endset %}
```

If you're stuck on an older version (like the jinja2 from google app engine), you would probably be best doing the processing before passing it into the template, if possible.